# “INVALID FILE NAME: MUST CONTAIN ONLY [a-z0-9_.]“ for sound files in Android Studio

Tags: android, audio

I am creating an Android App that has sound files in the `res/raw` folder. 50 of them. They are all named `s1.mp3`, `s2.mp3`, `s3.mp3` etc.

I have done some searches and found that everyone getting this error only gets it because their file has a capital letter in it. Mine doesn't.

The error started by specifically pointing out that `s37.mp3` had the incorrect file name. I then moved that file away completely, thinking that it had a bug or something. When I tried to recompile, it said `s38.mp3` had the problem. I then moved all files after `s36.mp3` away and it then pointed to `s12.mp3` as the problem.

So obviously the Android Studio sees a problem with all of the sound files' names. When I look at the navigation bar on the left of the screen, I see that all the sound files have their regular names, but their extensions are in caps (.MP3). Of course this cannot be the problem, right?

[image]

Comment: "but their extensions are in caps (.MP3)" -- most likely, that is the problem. Change their extensions to `.mp3` and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: Great. It took forever to rename, but it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw your image and you have a file called `s30.MP3`, remember **`FILES MUST CONTAIN ONLY [a-z0-9_.]`**“ -

the file `s30.MP3` must be renamed to `s30.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

File names must be lowercase a-z or underscore.
Hope this helps anyone else.